# Why dump command of pig is taking so much time to execute?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am running simple dump command in single mode but it is taking a long time to execute, same thing is happening for store.

But I noticed that its happening when I am running pig in mapReduce mode.

What can be the reason and how to resolve it?

Comment: You need to tell what is long time. How long it is taking?

Comment: It would also help if you post your code and size of your data etc.